# Angular2 and Ng2Bootstrap issue : ComponentLoaderFactory

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular

Here is the problem :

I'm actually trying the ng2-bootstrap examples available there :

http://valorkin.github.io/ng2-bootstrap/#/

What I do, is copy/paste examples in a angular2 project I created, using system.js, my actual system.js config looks like this :

```
System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    map: {
        '@angular/core': '../node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        //...
    }
});
System.import('main');
```

I actually tried these examples with no problems :

```
CAROUSEL
COLLAPSE
DROPDOWNS
```

For any of these examples, when I declare them in the imports part of the app.module, I do use the forRoot() function :

```
..., DatepickerModule.forRoot(), CarouselModule.forRoot(), ...
```

But, when I try to copy/paste the "DATEPICKER" example, I get this issue :

```
EXCEPTION: Error in templates/datepicker-demo.component.html:24:6 caused by: No provider for ComponentLoaderFactory!
```

This is the line where a "datepicker" tag is opened.
So what I tried then, is to declare "component-loader" in the systemJs map like this :

```
'ng2-bootstrap/component-loader': '../node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/component-loader/index.js'
```

AND declare it in the "providers" section of the app module. But, this does not solve anything, this leads to a new error concerning positioning.js which is not found...

What is this "component-loader" class, and how to use/include it properly?

Thanks for reading/help

Answer (score 0):

In your app.module:

You need a `entryComponent` field in `@NgModule()` in your module file because you are loading your Bootstrap Components dynamically.
Add your bootstrap components in the entryComponents array as shown below :

```
@NgModule({
declaration: [],
imports: [],
  entryComponents: [DatePickerComponent, ModalComponent,..]
})
```

Comment: So, I keep declaring my modules in the import part with the forRoot() function, AND I add the entryComponents part with the components? Actually I declared them in a "declarations" array...

Comment: You have to declare them in "declarations array" as well as "entryComponents" array. And you need to declare only NgbModule.forRoot() instead of  DatepickerModule.forRoot(), CarouselModule.forRoot() inimports array. Also  import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';